# I don't have a raw folder in Eclipse, after making a new Android file project. What can I do?

Tags: android, eclipse

Sorry, I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm learning only now the Android Java specific language. I have a book, from I want to learn, but I don't have a raw folder when I make a new project. How can I make it? Or I deleted it before? I don't know, because I'm only try to discover the Eclipse IDE, and I made some mistakes. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you mean the `raw` folder, not file .. and no, it's not default, you have to create it: right-click on the `res` folder, select New...Folder, and enter the name of the folder, like in the image:
[image]

Then, you can create new files there, either with drag-and-drop, or again right click on the folder name, New... File.

Answer (score 9):

You don't get every standard folder made for when you make a new Android project, raw folder included. Just right click your res folder in Eclipse, select new, and then folder. Make the new folder have the name raw and press Finish. Just put your raw files in there to use them.