# raw folder created error in app

Tags: android, video, directory

Hi I am **new** to android and i am trying to exploring the **eclipse**
i was trying to add video to my app , for which when i google to where to put my videos , i found under res i have to create a new **raw folder** , i follow that and when i create a raw folder and add  **video** file in that it create **errors**

this is the link from where i get references

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806883/i-dont-have-a-raw-folder-in-eclipse-after-making-a-new-android-file-project-w

please suggest do i need to anything else or where i a doing mistake .

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: when i pu any file in this folder i got cross on my app   
my file name is StepUp2-Final Dance.mp4

Comment: change the name of StepUp2-Final Dance.mp4 to some simple format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

- Create raw folder in package in workspace
- Copy the video file to this folder
- Rename file to a standard android resource standard (no space or
  dashes or upper cases)
- Refresh your workspace through eclipse
- Refer video in your code using id

Hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

you should rename your files in the raw folder : `StepUp2-Final Dance.mp4` 
in general, any file in resouces folder ( `res/*` )  **should not contain a space , upper case or dashes.**
try to rename your video to this for example and clean your project : `step_up2_final_dance.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps the name of the vidéo : use only lower case, no space, no dash.

And what is your error by the way ?

Comment: We're not answering when we're not sure answer

Comment: yes the name in lowercase and no space
  
when i pu any file in this folder i got cross on my app my file name is StepUp2-Final Dance.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question:

When I was directly copying the file to raw folder it was showing error,

but when I went to raw folder and right click on it, add image - it worked